# Pi as Bluetooth headset

Tags: bluetooth

I am having problem setting up Pi as Bluetooth headset - HSP profile (I do not need/want A2DP, HFP, etc. Just the simplest HSP.) In short, Pi should be seen as a headset by any device that can connect to BT headsets

OS: stretch (2017-11-29)

pulseaudio and ofono successfully installed as per https://scribles.net/enabling-hands-free-profile-on-raspberry-pi-raspbian-stretch-by-using-pulseaudio/

ASUS USB BT dongle is provisioned and recognized as per http://youness.net/raspberry-pi/bluetooth-headset-raspberry-pi-3-ad2p-hsp

Trusting and pairing work fine. Connecting fails after few seconds (it connects then immediately disconects.)  The handset reports 'service not supported'. Obviously, headset profile is not listed (see below). Attempts to change class to something that looks like headset failed.

All help appreciated.

```
[bluetooth]# show
Controller xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
    Name: zz
    Alias: zz
    Class: 0x0c0404
    Powered: yes
    Discoverable: yes
    Pairable: yes
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d052B
    Discovering: no
```

Edit: it works as headset **only** with MacBook Pro (Sierra) and nothing else (tried many handsets, Windows machines, etc.) What is special about MacBook?

It fails on everything else, after connecting, with:

```
[CHG] Device zz:zz:zz:zz:zz:zz ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device zz:zz:zz:zz:zz:zz Connected: no
```

Edit2: **SOLVED**

1. Manually install newer versions of Ofono (source) and Pulseaudio (from Buster packages)

Ofono 1.21:

ofono-1.21.tar.gz

Pulseaudio 11 package and and deps:

libpulse0_11.1-4_armhf.deb
pulseaudio_11.1-4_armhf.deb
pulseaudio-module-bluetooth_11.1-4_armhf.deb

2. No need to edit /etc/pulse/default.pa at all
3. Edit /etc/dbus-1/system.d/ofono.conf and add

(see https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Bluetooth/ for explanation)

Answer (score 1):

1. Manually install newer versions of Ofono (source) and Pulseaudio (from Buster packages)

Ofono 1.21:

ofono-1.21.tar.gz

Pulseaudio 11 package and and deps:

libpulse0_11.1-4_armhf.deb
pulseaudio_11.1-4_armhf.deb
pulseaudio-module-bluetooth_11.1-4_armhf.deb

2. No need to edit /etc/pulse/default.pa at all
3. Edit /etc/dbus-1/system.d/ofono.conf and add

(see https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Bluetooth/ for explanation)

Comment: Upgrade pulseaudio from  10.0-1 to 11.1-4 works for me. (btw used this repo http://archive.kali.org/kali/pool/main/p/pulseaudio/)

Comment: Looks like in 2018 the on-board chip got a update to allow HFP/HSP: https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-bluetooth/commit/0dffacec9452b975ed7c17b530e4f230ea17b727 but there is no instructions how this will help to use it? (I actually have Raspberry Pi 4)

Answer (score 0):

I'm very happy with [bt-speaker](https://github.com/lukasjapan/bt-speaker)
A simple Bluetooth Speaker Daemon designed for the Raspberry Pi